# The result returned by getPalterly method is wrong. (hint: do not return the correct string )

Tags: java, string

I have this task:
Write a class with Guttery name specifier and the public
which contain visible public static method called getPalterly
and the arguments dhangar, puccinoid type string and
which returns string. The method checks getPalterly
if dhangar string is part of puccinoid and if
the above proposal is verified returns the first 3
characters string dhangar. If the above link does not
verified then returns as a string the length of the string
dhangar.

I have written this code:

```
public class Guttery  {
    public static String  getPalterly(String dhangar , String puccinoid) {
        int g = dhangar.length();

        if (puccinoid.contains(dhangar)) {
            return dhangar.substring(g - 3 , g);
        } else {
            int a = dhangar.length();
            String b = Integer.toString(a);
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

But i have this error:
The result returned by getPalterly method is wrong. (hint: do not return the correct string )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write you should return the **first 3** characters ?

Then :

```
if (puccinoid.contains(dhangar)) {
        return dhangar.substring(0 , 3);
```